# Prolog list and filtering

Tags: list, prolog, filtering

I have a problem with a Prolog exercise. I'm trying to study Computer Science alone at my home, and I'm doing a series of exercises I've taken from the Internet.

The question is the following;

> Construct a predicate called `filteringPairsAtoms/3` so that given an atom (first argument), and a list of pairs, unify a third parameter with the filtered list of pairs by selecting only the pairs that have the first component as the atom of the first argument.

Example

```
filteringPairsAtoms(sA,[[basA,absAb],[ab,bbsA],[sA,abbsB],[bsA,sAsB],[sA,bb]],X)
```

must result in

```
X = [[sA,abbsB],[sA,bb]]
```

I'm trying to solve it but I don't have anyone to ask, because I'm learning alone, and don't have a professor to write to or something.

Any help is welcome.

Thanks!!!

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please provide the steps that you have tried and any specific questions that you may have from that.

Comment: I've used recursive search on the list, but i dont have any positive results yet.

Comment: you can show us anything you got. any code, any attempt is OK. so we can see where's *your* difficulty. otherwise it's shooting in the dark.

Comment: @Emily_1990 It's a bit off-topic, but since you study on your own, you can first spend time on more structured and simple tasks like the classical [Ninety-Nine Prolog Problems](http://www.ic.unicamp.br/~meidanis/courses/mc336/2009s2/prolog/problemas/). Then you can add helpful details to your questions like "I don't understand this problem, but I do understand these and these simpler related problems" (and in this case even a [rubber duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) may help you no less than a professor.)

Comment: Adding to Kirill, there are a lot of great Prolog books for self-study, and the language hasn't changed much in a few decades, so even fairly old books can be helpful still. I would recommend _Programming in Prolog_ by Clocksin & Mellish or _Art of Prolog_ by Sterling & Shapiro.

Answer (score 3):

You can start from what you already have:

```erlang
filteringPairsAtoms(sA, [[basA,absAb],[ab,bbsA],[sA,abbsB],[bsA,sAsB],[sA,bb]], X) :-
    X = [[sA,abbsB],[sA,bb]].
```

That's as good a start as any. But we know more: it must be the case that

```erlang
filteringPairsAtoms(sA, [[sA,abbsB],[bsA,sAsB],[sA,bb]], X) :-
    X = [[sA,abbsB],[sA,bb]].

%% and
filteringPairsAtoms(sA, [[bsA,sAsB],[sA,bb]], X) :-
    X = [[sA,bb]].

%% and
filteringPairsAtoms(sA, [[sA,bb]], X) :-
    X = [[sA,bb]].

%% and
filteringPairsAtoms(sA, [], X) :-
    X = [].
```

Comparing the sequential clauses, we also notice that it must be

```erlang
filteringPairsAtoms(sA, [[sA,abbsB] | [[bsA,sAsB],[sA,bb]] ], X) :-
    sA = sA,
    X = [[sA,abbsB] | Y],
    filteringPairsAtoms(sA, [[bsA,sAsB],[sA,bb]], Y).
```

(this is just the first two clauses from above, combined); and

```erlang
filteringPairsAtoms(sA, [[bsA,sAsB] | [[sA,bb]] ], X) :-
    dif( sA, bsA),
    X = Y,
    filteringPairsAtoms(sA, [[sA,bb]], Y).
```

All that's left for you to do, is *generalize* this by replacing concrete terms with logical variables. Like this:

```erlang
filteringPairsAtoms(SA, [Head | Tail ], X) :-
    Head = [BsA, _]
    dif( SA, BsA),
    X = Y,
    filteringPairsAtoms(SA, Tail, Y).
```

and carry this out fully to the end.

Comment: Thank you for the fast answer. I've tried to run the script doing quite modifications, but after all, i'm getting this error: {"code":500, "message":"Arguments are not sufficiently instantiated"}

Comment: I tried to give you hints here so you'd get to the working code yourself... You can post new question on StackOverflow, including your full new code, the test query, and the response you get from your Prolog prompt (also please specify what implementation you're using) including full error message. Also include link to this question, for context.