# Compressing a list in prolog with run length encoding

Tags: prolog, run-length-encoding

I am learning prolog and have been struggling with a homework question. The question is:

"Write a predicate myencode/2 that takes the uncompressed list as a first parameter and returns the compressed list as shown as the second parameter. For example".

```
myencode([],X) should yield X = [].
myencode(['a','b','b','c','c','c','d','d'],X) should yield X = [ (a, 1), (b, 2), (c, 3), (d, 2)] .
myencode(['a','p','p','l','e'],X) should yield X = [ (a, 1), (p, 2), (l, 1), (e, 1)] .
```

The questions advises:

"You may find it useful to write a tempencode/2 function that translates a list like `['a','a','a','b','b','c','a','a']`
into `[('a',1),('a',1),('a',1),('b',1),('b',1),('c',1),('a',1),('a',1)]`

So far I've been able to get the tempencode function to work

```
myencode(L,X) :- tempencode(L,X).

tempencode([],[]).
tempencode([H|T],[(H,1)|X]) :- tempencode(T,X).
```

which gives me

```
?- myencode(['a','a','a','b','b','c'],X).
X = [ (a, 1), (a, 1), (a, 1), (b, 1), (b, 1), (c, 1)].
```

I am not sure how to proceed from here, any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: I don't find it particularly useful to use `tempencode/2` as described. You should first find a suitable algorithm to encode the input list, describe it recursively. After you have that then its a matter of writing it in prolog which would be quite straightforward. A hint: you should probably need to write a procedure that receives the input list, the current "item", the current number of times that item has been already processed, and an output list.

Comment: Try it first or take a look at this answer by Will Ness: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61461089/prolog-run-length-encoding (sadly, the OP never okayed the response given; there should be a "community override")

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prolog Run Length Encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61461089/prolog-run-length-encoding)

Comment: I did try the answer from that post before but I only got "false" when I ran it rather than the list.